# GitHub Graph QL Authentication via a Github App

Tags: github-api, github-graphql, github-app

I am just wondering, did anyone manage to authenticate into the Github GraphQL API with using a Github App and how?

The purpose of this is to write a script that pulls information from Github with the GraphQL API, but uses an app for authentication - so it is not user dependant and if a user leaves the organisation it doesn't take the functionality of the script with him.

The aim is to have a script that pulls all the Dependabot alerts from all the repos and pushes them to a Google spreadsheet.

I think I read somewhere Github does not recommend using a user service account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this guide](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps) to "Authenticate as an installation", which generates a token.

Then I set a http header to: `"Authorization: token YOUR_INSTALLATION_ACCESS_TOKEN"`